# How to determine which window was moved/resized from WM_EXITSIZEMOVE message?

Tags: autoit, windows-messages

I've been processing all the numerous individual WM_MOVE, WM_SIZING, and WM_SIZE messages for a multiple-GUI/window application, but I've just learned of the WM_EXITSIZEMOVE message and would like to use it if it lets me avoid all those intermediate messages. But since no parameters are provided by that message, how can I determine which GUI/window has been moved or resized? Or is my thinking incorrect?

Comment: `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` is only sent to the window that has just been moved or sized, which means that when the window receives it, it is the one that was affected by the size/move operation. IOW, if you have windows A and B, and B is resized or moved, it will receive the message and A will not.

Answer (score -1):

All of the messages you reference are only sent to the window that was affected by that operation, which is why there are no parameters provided that identify the window. If the window receives it, it is the window that was just moved, sized, or is exiting size/move.

In other words, if you have windows A and B, and B is resized or moved, then it will receive the messages and window A will not.